# seekbar not updating when playing media file

Tags: android, listview, custom-adapter

I have listview with layout for playing audio.in that layout i have seekbar and play/pause button when i click on play button media file is played but seekbar not updating I also user Runnable and handler but it not works.
I am doing this in baseadapter inside getview method.
Please help me to sort out this

```
mAudioViewHolder.play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) {
    String yofile = "file://" + filepath;
    mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    try {

        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(yofile);

    } catch (IllegalArgumentException | SecurityException | IllegalStateException | IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        Log.e("Node", "ERRORSS Part 1 is" + e);

        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mAudioViewHolder.isPlaying = false;

                /**
                 * since audio is stop playing, remove its position value
                 * */
                playingAudioPosition = -1;
            }
        });
    }
    try {
        mediaPlayer.prepare();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("Node", "ERRORSS is Part 2 " + e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("Node", "ERRORSS is  Part 3 " + e);
    } // might take long! (for buffering, etc)
    mediaPlayer.start();

    mAudioViewHolder.progressBar.setMax(mediaPlayer.getDuration());


    Runnable mRunnable = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (mediaPlayer != null) {
                int mCurrentPosition = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition() / 1000;
                mAudioViewHolder.progressBar.setProgress(mCurrentPosition);
                Log.d("Node", "get current position " + mCurrentPosition);
            }

        }
    };
    Log.d("Node", "StartTime Updation " + mediaPlayer.getDuration() + "   " + mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
    mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 1000);
    //mAudioViewHolder.isPlaying = false;

}
```

Comment: Add your code snippet here for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling your runnable only once, when you need to call it every time you want to update your progress bar.

You can do this

```
Runnable mRunnable = new Runnable() {

                                        @Override
                                        public void run() {
                                            if(mediaPlayer != null){
                                                int mCurrentPosition = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition() / 1000;
                                                mAudioViewHolder.progressBar.setProgress(mCurrentPosition);
                                                Log.d("Node", "get current position "+mCurrentPosition);
                                                mHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
                                            }

                                        }
                                    };
                                    Log.d("Node", "StartTime Updation "+mediaPlayer.getDuration()+"   "+mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
                                    mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 1000);
```

Make sure you remove the runnable from the handler when you stop the playback.

```
mHandler.removeCallbacks(mRunnable);
```

Comment: its giving same problem and not updating

Comment: Try to run the runnable without a delay, and make sure your handler is set to run on the main thread.

Comment: my all this code is in getview method so i have to set handler in this method  mHandler=new Handler(); correct?  or should i do it in counstructor

Comment: Handler mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
You should also check for mediaPlayer.isPlaying() in your run()